# Changing Woocommerce Order Status based on order notes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been looking around to find a way to change our woocommerce orders status based on the order notes. We have a card processor that adds order notes when an order is approved, but it puts the order on hold because the card is only authorized not charged. We charge the card later once the order has been shipped, but we need the order to go into "processing" so we can export the order into our system so we can actually process the order (we don't process through woocommerce).

I found this code however, I'm wondering if this can be modified to pull what is in the order notes since our processor adds whether or not the card has been approved.

```
function mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete( $order_id ) {
    error_log( "Payment has been received for order $order_id" );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a Example which switch on hold order status with processing. you can use it or if need to add some more condition, please mention here or update it accordingly. Thanks**

```
function switch_hold_status_to_processing ($order_id) {
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
  $order->update_status('processing');
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'switch_hold_status_to_processing');
```

Comment: This is all orders, I want only the ones with specific notes in the order.

Comment: You can get all orders in this function with `wc_get_order_notes` and check if order content  is same as your note.

Comment: or share card processor note here, I will set conditions in hook and share with you.

Comment: We want to make sure that only orders with order notes containing this phrase: "charge authorized (Charge ID:"

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wc_get_order_notes($args)`](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_order_notes/) function to get the order notes in the specific order. It returns an array of order notes. Then you can loop through the array to find the order note you need. Then use an `if` statement to verify the content of the order note and update the status.

```
function mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete( $order_id ) {
    $order_notes = wc_get_order_notes([
        'order_id' => $order_id,
     ]);
    foreach ($order_notes as $order_note){
        if ($order_note->content == "Order verified"){
            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
            $order->update_status('processing');
            break;
        }
    }
    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'mysite_woocommerce_payment_complete', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: will this work one time? Or is this an ongoing thing that will automatically change new on-hold orders?

Comment: It is an ongoing process

Comment: What if I wanted to do this process if the order notes contain a phrase, not "is equal" to a phrase? Some of our order notes have dynamic content like order/charge IDs, so we would only want a specific phrase.